# PC not working correctly after downloading missing dll's . Need to delete them

Tags: windows-7, dll

A few days ago I updated my windows 7 ultimate (32 bits). After the updates I faced I couple of errors. All those errors were of programs like sidebar.exe, internet explorer, java, a lot of uninstalling programs, etc....  in the format in the picture below

[image]

All the missing dll files (7-10 files I think) have the name api-ms-win-downlevel-xxxxxxx-l1-1-0.dll where the "xxxxxxxx" is either ole32, user32, version,etc.... . Before doing anything I tried 'sfc /scannow' command in cmd, but there was no errors to fix.

So I tried looking for a solution and somehow ended downloading dll files from the internet (which screwed my pc). I tried doing stuff like 'regsvr32 /u api-ms-win-downlevel-xxxxx-l1-1-0.dll', deleting them manually, stopping their running processes, even trying to delete them with cmd  (which gave me "access denied") but all in vain

All I want now is to :-

1. Delete those dlls
2. Get those missing dlls without messing up my pc

It might be my HDD though,  I am currently checking whether it is or not

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30830/discussion-on-question-by-kai22315-pc-not-working-correctly-after-downloading-mi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You updated windows and as a result you have missing DLL files? Sounds fishy.
Even if this the case the situation now is worse because you downloaded system files from some crude website.

Your system might be infected with malware. You downloaded suspicious files.
The only thing to do here is: wipe your hard disk. Install your operating system from scratch and use a backup to get your files back. You probably can't clean your system anymore once compromised and even if Norton or whatever tells you it's clean you can't be sure.

Follow some best practices:

- don't use the Administrator account for an everyday user
- don't download DLL or other system files from the internet
- install Anti-Virus software
- do OS updates regularly
- do backups
- use brain.exe

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this is by far the most helpful one. definitely going to use  brain.exe next time LOL .

Answer (score 2):

This site is in fact a site that is blocked by Norton. Here is a report to what Norton says about the site you have downloaded the DLLs from.  https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=http:%2F%2Fwww.dll-files.com%2F&product=NSBU&version=22.5.4.24&lang=0901&source=toolbar    I would suggest getting Norton 360 or some other application to protect your machine since it seems your system let you blindly go into the site w/out warning.  I'm sure Norton 360 can repair your system.  While reviews of users say it's safe, Norton clearly shows many viruses coming from this site.

One thing to note, as of 2015 Norton 360 is now called Norton Security.  You may also want to use one of these coupon codes to save yourself some money.

http://promocodesforyou.com/index.php?id=305&gclid=Cj0KEQjw5MGxBRDiuZm2icXX2-sBEiQA619bq90Zh4VoAAdSNW5kFByqW_TJg4bCReWojvaP7hCzeNcaAnXX8P8HAQ

Comment: Thanks for the coupons , i am currently downloading it . I'll post about it if it solves my problem

Comment: Idk why , but norton installer doesn't even open

Comment: The virus might be blocking it.  You may want to boot in safe mode and then try it.

Comment: tried that , didn't  work

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  I would try to redownload it again.  If that doesn't work, I'd call Norton support.  I never had issues downloading Norton stuff and I've been using it for years.  Might be conflicting with something.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bits. I'll try re downloading it

Comment: Don't bother. If your computer is compromised, you will not be able to get it back. We can all talk about the possibility of getting it running, without wiping it, but you already downloaded random DLLs off the internet and are trying to install security software on a computer that has severe system problems. Without any offense meant, this is "above your pay grade." You need to wipe it out. @ramhound is correct: you ought to check your HD for physical problems, but if you are going to spend money, spend it on a new HD and reinstall.

Comment: It is the right solution for HD problems, virus, and hosed OS install. So you don't even need to diagnose it. If you get a new HD, it is plausible you can get important documents off of the old HD using e.g. a live CD Linux distribution.

Answer (score -3):

If it's a problem with system DLLs, you might be good using SFC to fix them.

1. Open Command Prompt as admin
2. type "sfc /SCANNOW"
3. Wait. The program should go through all of the system files and fix any dodgy ones.

Just an idea like. And it's free too. No norton shilling here, which might not have been on the other post, but it did look a bit like it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's the first thing i tried doing